# Access login protected page from external server ( Java, Groovy )

Tags: java, groovy, httpwebrequest, apache-commons

I am trying to get information from an internal site but which is login protected. Its a drupal site with some auth plugin.

Using

```
def slurper = new XmlSlurper()

def htmlParser = slurper.parse("http://theurl.se/pageIwantToGo")
```

returns a `403 ( Forbidden )` and I cannot access the contents on that page.

Same thing with:

```
new URL('http://theurl.se/pageIwantToGo:).getText()
```

From the browser I get a page with a login form that has a form_build_id which I probably need to read and submit together with the username and password.

How can I fool the site that I am browser so I can get access to the page?
Have tried using the groovy `HTTPBuilder` but couldn't get past the first step.

Comment: So [basic authentication with HTTPBuilder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/doc/auth.html) isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the security is implemented (Basic Authentication, Form login,....).
Most HTTP libraries in Java (ex: [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/)) support various security mechanism.

Fooling the site into thinking you're a browser will not get you in. If you want (but I don't think it's required), you can "fool" the site into thinking you're a browser by setting the appropriate User Agent in the HTTP header. (although this alone will not bypass the security)